# What is the right way to use C++ code in a Java code built with Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, makefile, build.gradle

I have been working on porting an Android native Java code base to a Plain Java application built with grade.

The build.gradle file of the Android code uses C++ code and this dependency has been declared as follows.

```
android {
    
    ...

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
}
```

What is the right way to do this for a java-application generated using Gradle(I followed [this](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-applications/) tutorial)

This is what MY build.grade file looks like so-far.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'demo.App'
}
```

I am using java 8, and my gradle version is 5.6.2, openjdk version 1.8.0_222

**EDIT:** After looking around a bit I know that it is possible to use C++ within java using JNI.

But android projects can be configured to use C++ at the time of creation, in android studio. Also, this project uses a makefile, not sure how this can be done with JNI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it to work, Here's how it worked, let's say I wanted to do System.loadLibrary("nativeCpp") from java

**Step 1:**

Move all the C++ code to `src/nativeCpp/cpp/` and remove the CMAKE.txt file.

**Step 2:**
Make sure build.gradle looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'cpp'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'        
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'demo.App'
}
run {
    systemProperty "java.library.path", file("${buildDir}/libs/nativeCpp/shared").absolutePath
}
model {
    platforms {
        x64 {
            architecture "x64"
        }
    }

    components {
        nativeCpp(NativeLibrarySpec) {


            binaries.all {
                cppCompiler.args '-I', "${org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().javaHome}/include"
                cppCompiler.args '-I', "${org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().javaHome}/include/linux"
                cppCompiler.args '-fPIC'
            }

        }
    }
}

run.dependsOn  'nativeCppSharedLibrary'
```

**Explanation:** Gradle requires you to save all the native components in src directory with their name, it refers to this directory(in my case src/nativeApp) to build your native code.

When you execute run task with `gradle run` any special instructions that you want to pass to the language compiler(in this case Java) are picked from run property in build.gradle. I wanted to pass `java.library.path` to make sure java can read it, without it you'll get `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` during build.

Next, we define the components inside the model block and how to build them, the instructions in `binaries.all` property translate to this in command line:

```
gcc -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/include -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -shared -o librendering.so native.cpp -fPIC
```

We specify the -I option to tell gcc compiler where is JNI located on our system. This path may vary for you.

This will compile your C++ code and store it in `/libs/nativeCpp/shared` where `run` can find it